# How Can I Make a Box Element Expand Automatically?

Tags: html, css, css-float

The link below shows a simplified version of a website I'm working on and the problem I'm presented with.

I have several encapsulated box elements. There is the main container, and several divs within that container that will hold content, as that content expands, I need the **container div to expand automatically**. I can't seem to accomplish this unless I add a specific height in the CSS.

[JSFiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/wguayan/E4vWz/5/)

HTML:

```
<body>
<div id="container">
    <div id="block1">
        <div id="one">one</div>
        <div id="two">two<br />two<br /></div>
        <div id="three">three<br />three<br />three<br /></div>
        <div id="four">four<br />four<br />four<br />four<br /></div>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
```

CSS:

```
#container {
width: 1050px;
margin: auto;
padding: 5px;
background-color: #ededf0;
background: 
   url("http://wguayan.comuv.com/brushed_metal_clear_apple.jpg") repeat;
}

#one, #two, #three, #four {
border-width: 1px;
border-color: black;
border-style: solid;
background-color: white;
border-radius:6px;
-moz-border-radius:6px;
/* Firefox 3.6 and earlier */
}

#one {
width: 100px;
position: relative;
top: 0px;
left: 0px;
padding: 10px;
box-shadow: 9px 9px 12px #888888;
}

#two {
float: left;
width: 100px;
position: relative;
top: 0px;
left: 0px;
padding: 5px;
text-align: center;
box-shadow: 9px 9px 12px #888888;
}

#three {
float: left;
width: 100px;
position: relative;
top: 0px;
left: 0px;
padding: 10px;
box-shadow: 9px 9px 12px #888888;
}

#four {
float: left;
width: 100px;
position: relative;
top: 0px;
left: 0px;
padding: 10px;
box-shadow: 9px 9px 12px #888888;
}

#block1 {
width: 100%;
border-width: 1px;
border-color: black;
border-style: solid;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just apply `overflow: hidden` to #block1

Comment: This suggestion worked, however, I ran into essentially the same problem. If you look at my CSS, you'll see that I purposefully zeroed out top and left relative positioning. So now the problem is that when I start moving the DIVS around with positioning, and they are filled with content and expand, they expand beyond the body element: http://jsfiddle.net/wguayan/drWSj/